# DJANGO ORM - Filtrar Ultimo registro por fecha y devuelva un lista

Tags: django, date, orm, filtro

Les agradezco me ayuden con la siguiente consulta.

Tengo una tabla `(modelo, managed=False)` que esta siendo poblada por un demonio el cual graba la temperatura de 20 refrigeradores cada 60 minutos. El modelo ya lo tengo importado en Django y puedo hacer consultas básicas del mismo.

Modelo:

```
    class Refrigerador(models.Model):
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        refrigerador_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
        temperatura = models.DecimalField(null=True, blank=True)
        fecha_registro = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

        class Meta:
          managed = False
```

Requiero hacer una consulta que me traiga por fecha el ultimo registro que se grabe para cada uno de los refrigeradores. Algo así.

```
refrigerador_id        fecha_registro                   temperatura
2313                  2020-04-22 12-33-45                  4.1
8765                  2020-04-22 11-05-33                  3.2
3443                  2020-04-22 13-00-12                  3.8
6456                  2020-04-22 11-58-03                  3.0
```

La tabla puede tener hasta un millón de registros. requiero que la consulta solo me genere el ultimo registro recibido de temperatura del refrigerador.

He intentado esto.

Con `last()`, devuelve un `(uno)` solo valor o registro. el Ultimo basado en fecha.

```
    Refrigerador.objects.order_by('refrigerador_id', 'fecha_registro').last()
```

Lo mismo ocurre con  `latest ()`  retorna un único registro

```
    Refrigerador.objects.latest('fecha_registro')
```

Por ahí es el camino, pero se requiere el ultimo registro de cada `"refrigerdor_id"`: es decir 20 registros con su ultima fecha que llego la temperatura. Creo que se debe combinar con `Max('fecha_registro')` pero no encuentro manera lógica de combinarlo o si se puede usar.

Intente con `__range`, pero por ahí no es.

Otra camino puede ser con `select_related()` pero esta tabla `(modelo)` no tiene relaciones con ningún otro modelo. Y si se usa sin tener el filtro de las fechas retorna todos los registros de la tabla.

Agredezco su ayuda...

Comment: Mencionaste que quieres hacer *"una consulta que traiga por fecha el **ultimo registro** que se grabe para cada uno de los refrigeradores"*, después dices que quieres *"**20 registros** con su ultima fecha que llego la temperatura"*, por favor explícate bien y especifica que exactamente quieres.

Comment: Hola. Tratare de explicarlo de manera diferente. Me llegan datos de 20 refrigeradores cada hora (60 min). Requiero obtener el ultimo dato de temperatura que ha llegado de cada uno de los refrigeradores. Este ultimo dato, la idea es filtrarlo por fecha (ultima fecha). Que el resultado sea algo parecido a lo que se muestra en el segundo bloque de la pregunta inicial. (refrigerador_id, fecha_registro, temperatura). Trato de dar la mayor cantidad de información para que sea entendible para muchos. Aunque aveces esto hace que se generen confusiones.

Comment: No te entiendo, dices que quieres obtener el ultimo dato de temperatura de los últimos 20 refrigeradores, y que este dato (la temperatura), filtrarlo por fecha, pero un `DecimalField` no es una fecha, lo cual es imposible. Por otra parte, si quieres obtener los últimos 20 registros de un QuerySet, seria así: `<QuerySet>[-20:]`, o puedes hacer algo así: `Refrigerador.objects.order_by('fecha_registro')[:20]`, de esta manera obtienes los primeros 20 registros que querías.

Comment: Julio Cesar, gracias por intentar ayudar. Debes leer el requerimiento completo para que entiendas el contexto de la consulta. Se explica amplia mente la solicitud y las pruebas hechas para intentar solucionarlo. Si no consideras el contexto completo no hay caso. Saludos cordiales

Comment: Da nada, no te entendia muy bien  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por recomendación de grupo Django-es seguí el enfoque y la consulta en principio ya funciona. Es así:

```
Refrigerador.objects.values('refrigerador_id')
            .distinct()
            .annotate(Max('fecha_registro'))
```

Con eso se obtienen los datos de la manera como los requiero.

Agradezco si alguien tiene otro enfoque para probar.

Answer (score 0):

Investigando di con algo parecido, ya que yo también requiero lo mismo que tú jeje

```
Modelo.objects.filter(campo_1 = condicion_1, campo_2 = condicion_2).order_by("id", "-campo_a_filtrar").distinct("id")
```

Lo que se hace es ordenar de mayor a menor de a cuerdo al campo que se necesita filtrar y se utiliza la función distinct() para obtener solo los primeros valores diferentes.
Espero que esto ayude ya que me tuvo mucho tiempo investigando jeje